# Plotting 256 hexagons inside a big hexagon

Tags: plotting, drawing

I wonder how can I draw 256 hexagons inside a big hexagon?
I want the 256 hexagons to have different colours, namely:
1 black, 8 red, 28 blue, 56 orange, 70 green, 56 yellow, 28 purple, 8 cyan, and 1 grey.

Comment: Can you be clearer about the goal? Is the big one composed of them or they are just inside? Do their positions matter? Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you have a specific layout in mind you should tell; 256 is not [a centered hexagonal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_hexagonal_number) which would be the most obvious starting point to think of.

Comment: I am trying to put them inside, I am not sure if 256 can be composed as 256/6 is not a round number. Each colour group should sit next to each other with the order I wrote. I am very new to Graphics package the only thing I tried is Graphics[Polygon[CirclePoints[6]]] but I have no idea on how to proceed

Answer (score 2):

A hexagon [cannot be broken into 256 smaller hexagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_hexagonal_number). It can be broken into 217 (if each edge has 9 small ones) or 271 (if each edge has 10 small ones).

Such plots are easy to make with the `IGLatticeMesh` function of [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
IGLatticeMesh["Hexagonal", Polygon@CirclePoints[9, 6]]
```

[image]

The result is a `MeshRegion`. You can colour cells using the `MeshCellStyle` option. It is unclear from your question how you want to colour them.